# Cant assign value to input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for(Imagedocu.new) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :image %>
<%= f.text_field :patient_id, params[:id]%>
<%= f.text_field :type %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

How you can see i assign a value to one of the inputs:

```
<%= f.text_field :patient_id, params[:id]%>
```

I dont know why but now somehow i get the error:

```
undefined method `merge' for "73539":String
```

`73539` is the params[:id]! What do i wrong?

Comment: You should share your controller and/or model code, as that's likely where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a form that already contains an object (`Imagedocu.new`), so it "grabs" the value for patient_id directly from this object. If you want to overwrite this value, use this:

```
<%= f.text_field :patient_id, value: params[:id] %>
```

**OR** initialize the `Imagedocu.new` with a patient_id equal to params[:id]:

```
<%= form_for( Imagedocu.new(patient_id: params[:id]) ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :image %>
  <%= f.text_field :patient_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :type %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**But a cleaner way is** to initialize the new Imagedocu object in the controller's action:

```
# controller
def new
  @imagedocu = Imagedocu.new(patient_id: params[:id])
  # etc.

# view
<%= form_for( @imagedocu ) do |f| %>
  # etc.
```